# AVD emulator Android Studio crash, a while after i turn it on

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

My AVD crashed when i start running and use it. I don't know what the error is, because it immediately disappear/crashed. I've tried it pixel, pixel2, and custom hardware profile to change the Graphics option to Software GLES 2.0. I have the video of my error, so hope you guys know the problem https://youtu.be/sCEWWj3R1wk.

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXvsX.png)

note: i run it on laptop with 16gb ram, ryzen 5, rtx3050, amd radeon graphics

Comment: Weird behavior... Try to launch emulator without tool window(propably working unstable). To do this: go to Settings(Preferences) -> Tools -> Emulator, then uncheck "Launch in a tool window".